# How to get a front-end event to show up in Path Analyzer?

Tags: events, path-analyzer

We're using Angular to handle site's front-end, and I'd like to add some events which happen there, like opening "new" pages based on JavaScript to Path Analyzer.

This is how I tried to do it:

```cs
var pageEventData = new PageEventData("Page Visited", new System.Guid("7DAF6F40-87EA-4594-B977-4994E5B439D3"))
{
    ItemId = new System.Guid("92B09B21-3B5B-43E3-939D-A1C62779AED9"),
    Data = title,
    Text = "page "+ title + " was visited"
};

Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.PreviousPage.Register(pageEventData);
```

(where "7DAF6..." is id of /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Page visited event and "92B.. " just a random id of one of the page items I use for testing)

And this seems wrong, even though the event actually gets registered to Mongo's db.Interactions table as a PageEvent of 'Page visited' type, I don't see it in Path Analyzer. Is there actually a way to simulate a new page being visited and get a new node to be added to Sitecore's Path Analyzer?

Here is an example of what gets registered in the db.interactions table: https://gist.github.com/epetrashen/92d2fe0e8b882932e2cf88cebe8868f3

Comment: If it's being registered in MongoDB then though code is working. It sounds like there is something missing in the other end after the data has been aggregated. Have you tried Deploy Marketing Definitions on the Control Panel?

Comment: @IanGraham yes, I actually haven't been able to make Path Analyzer work before I attempted Deploy Marketing Definitions, so now it's been done.

Comment: Have you deployed the maps under sitecore/admin/PathAnalyser.aspx yet?

Comment: @IanGraham yes, deployed all of the maps and also tried rebuilding them & pretty much all of the other options available under sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx. 
So do you think if an event is registered in db.interactions as sitecore's "Page Visited" PageEvent it's enough for it to become a new node in Path Analyzer? The "real sitecore pages" I visit while testing this are actually being shown in PA, it's only a problem for these javascript-based pages I try to register myself, so I thought I must be lacking something.

Comment: Oh ok, can you give a bit of info around how you are calling the server side logic. How is the controller set up?

Comment: @IanGraham when a javascript button is clicked, $http.get("/trackfakepages/?title="+title) is called.
trackfakepages is a sitecore page (btw a visit to "TrackFakePages" is displayed in PA) which has a controller rendering on it, which triggers the Track method of an MVC controller, which contains the fragment of code I initially cited in my question. (The reason it's done in a kind of clumsy way is because the other controller which actually deals with all the other actions on the javascript page is an ODataController => has no session => can't track anything)

Comment: @elellle Could you edit your question and attach an interaction object that is saved to MongoDB with your custom events? You can use the JSON representation, or a screenshot with all relevant interaction fields visible.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko thank you for showing interest in this question. I've added a link to the gist containing a JSON representation of an interaction object to the question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this I think. In Mongo's `dbo.interactions` pages are stored in a nested array, and page events are stored as a nested array within each page. Apparently, my mistake was that I've been expecting PageEvents of "Page visited" type to be represented in Path Analyzer as nodes, but what actually gets displayed there are Pages themselves.
So now each time a front-end event I'm interested in happens, I'm using a fake page that is "visited" and edit its `Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Url.Path` and `Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Item.Id` so that it looks like another item (my JavaScript-based page) was being visited. Which is clumsy but hey, it works! :)

Comment: That's a clever solution! I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Awesome work around! You can also use Experience Maps instead of Page Maps, which are only built from pages. Experience Maps allow you to have page events, goals, outcomes, etc. in xDB. You can create your own too :)